# Differences between RHEL5 NFS and Solaris 2.6 NFS

Tags: linux, solaris, nfs

I have a legacy application (LabVIEW 7.0) running on my Sun Ultra 5 workstation running Solaris 2.6.  I want to use a RHEL5 server to store all files so that I am not cluttering the small HDD on the Sun.  I have found that the LabVIEW file browser has a bug which prevents it from seeing some files and folders in an NFS share mounted from RHEL5, but this problem is not present when using an NFS share mounted from another Ultra 5 using Solaris 2.6.  I believe in both cases NFSv3 is being used.  Is there some way I can make the RHEL5 NFS behave more like Solaris 2.6?  If I make a new partition on the RHEL5 box and install OpenSolaris, will this behave more like Solaris 2.6?  I am locked into using this buggy LabVIEW program, so somehow I need to make it work.

Comment: Which minor version of RHEL5 are you using? Eg. with RHEL5.9 there is a known problem with NFS (https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/306063); and NFS from Solaris to RHEL5.9 server behaves differently than to a RHEL5.1 server.

Comment: @oliver the NFS bug in your attached link is very similar to what I am seeing. LabVIEW has a "list files" function that is very similar to the "ls" command. This command has the same kind of problem that I see when trying to use the LabVIEW file browser. Strangely, I do not have this problem when using the ls command in bash, only when I try to list files using LabVIEW.

Comment: IIRC for me the first NFS problem was solved by upgrading to kernel 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5 (as mentioned in https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-0747.html) or even kernel 2.6.18-348.12.1.el5. Still have no solution for the problems between Solaris and RHEL5.9, unfortunately.

Comment: @oliver my kernel version is 2.6.18-128.el5. I will try to upgrade to 2.6.18-348.12.1.el5 to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Ultra 5 is IDE, and if you can remove the floppy drive, there's space for another commodity internal HD of up to 120GB. That may be the easiest option of all.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without any references/explanations about the bug you are talking about. In any case, OpenSolaris has much better chances to match Solaris 6 implementation details than Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

SPARC binaries are compatible from 2.6 up to 10. Have you tried running LabVIEW 7.0 on a later version of Solaris ?